# Element type "application" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>" #2

Tags: android

I keep getting an error that says, "Element type "application" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.thenewboston.sammy"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
```

I'm getting the error right below this:

```
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the right form, see if you didn't close some tags.

```
<application android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    ...>
    <activity ...>
        <intent-filter>    
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: three dots mean something goes there as of attributes, for example:
http://s21.postimg.org/8e88erg1j/Capture.jpg

Answer (score 1):

As my friend said , check the right format

For me It was like this :

BEFORE :

```
<activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity" android:label="display_message_activity" 
</activity>
```

AFTER:

```
<activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity" android:label="display_message_activity" >
</activity>
```

Then the error disappeared

Answer (score 1):

In my case, a comment had been placed (by the build tools?) inside the application tag:

```
    <application android:allowBackup="true"
        <!-- android:debuggable="true" -->
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/GdxTheme">
```

After I removed the entire debuggable=true comment line - everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this error for a completely different reason. For some reason Android Studio had replaced every instance of the string `name` with `"name"` (e.g. it wrapped them all in double quotes) in my XML. It completely broke everything.

I had to clear out the double quotes from everything, clean the project and rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a flutter developer and you're getting this exception you must know there are two `AndroidManifest` file in your flutter project. One is inside debug folder and another one is main folder. My main folder `AndroidManifest` is ok and well formatted but `AndroidManifest` in debug folder is not ok and not well formatted due to a git conflict.[image]

you must fix this.