# Element type "activity" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Tags: android, eclipse, xml-parsing

I've read up on forum posts about similar errors, but nothing I read works. It looks like my formatting is fine, but I keep getting the indicated error. I've tried refreshing the project and cleaning the project as well as restarting Eclipse entirely.

```
<manifest
    ... >
    <application
        ... >
        <activity
            android:name="com.myNamespace.myPackage.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: can you post the full `manifest`?Formatting seems to be proper.

Comment: Check @androbat comment here and my comment 
[element type must be followed problem !][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537539/element-type-application-must-be-followed-by-either-attribute-specifications/26110631#26110631

Answer (score 8):

In your manifest you must have forget to close one of the attribute. Check out your manifest file closely and make sure you have closed all the tags.

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same isssue but I found that it was coming because of copying and pasting the code in xml file.

Please try to type the code manually and see. Hope the error will not come.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.myNamespace.myPackage"
      android:versionCode="12" android:versionName="2.2.0">
      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
        <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false">
        <activity android:name="com.myNamespace.myPackage.MainActivity"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error until I figured out that the activity tag needs to open and close on the same line. It's not a written syntax but my error was gone when I wrote the whole tag in one line instead of on separate lines. You should try it like this:

```
<application>
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"> </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I develop in Eclipse on a Mac. When I copy items (both from within Code and/or from a webpage (like Stackoverflow or so) I often get this error. I believe that the copy/paste mechanism is not functioning completely well.

What I do to solve this error, is just typing the complete line (no copy/paste!), all over again.

When I have copied a block I see that the error moves to the next line, which you have to retype also.

Very time consuming and frustrating, but this really works!